# How to create a Nerdtree node that uses tmpl.html

Tags: vim, vi, macvim, nerdtree

I am using nerdtree with MacVim but I can't figure out how to create a node and have it use my ~/.vim/skel/tmpl.html file when I create a new node. I type m - a to create the node. If I use a vim command to create a file it uses my template. Is there a way to create a node in NerdTree that would recognize and use the template?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this really answers you questions but why not copy the template to your current folder using vim's cp command.

Comment: So you are saying every time I want to create html files with a template, I would have to put a template file in the folder I want to create it in? Seems counter productive. I would think NerdTree would just read my config file like doing a regular vim